# Использование рекурсии в handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Собственно потребовалось написать шаблон для рекурсивного вывода меню на handlebars.js. Навскидку нагуглил только решения из emberjs. Нужно с минимальными дополнениями это сделать. Может можно обойтись хелпером?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Торопился и [проглядел](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/#partials). Печаль, что этого нет на их главной странице, а пришлось искать.